# Using RoboFragment with FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, roboguice

I've been trying to use RoboGuice and fragments with no luck. I have a fragment that extends `RoboFragment`, and an activity that extends `RoboActivity`, but it seems that within the `RoboActivity`, the method `getFragmentManager` is incompatible with `RoboFragment`.

It looks like `RoboFragment` extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragmentment` but `getFragmentManager` requires `android.app.Fragment`.

How is this meant to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As always I worked our my problem within 10 minutes of posting (sorry)!

I needed my activity to extend RoboFragmentActivity, which then exposed the getSupportFragmentManager method - which returns the android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager which is obviously compatible with android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Matt